# Remove title and name from sidebar yet keep them in the bottom part of the presentation

Tags: beamer, titles

I need to write a **beamer** presentation for my upcoming thesis defense and chose the **Palo Alto** style.

My problem with the Palo Alto style is, that my name and the title of the presentation should
not appear in the sidebar, yet appear in the footer of the presentation.

(Therefore short and long name/title don't work since providing an empty short name/title would also leave the footer empty).

Is there an option / (if not, workaround) for suppressing author and title in the sidebar only?

Thanks in advance, any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: MWE]

Just taking the solution of [boodworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89890/11604) to clean the autor and title of the side bar, before of PaloAlto theme you can add an outher theme as `shadow` to have these elements at the bottom:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow} 
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\title{The title}
\author{The Author}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section Test}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what you mean about the footer since there is no footer in the `PaloAlto` theme. But for suppressing the title and name in the sidebar one needs to alter the template. 
Just add

```
  \makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother
```

some when after you loaded the theme. It redefines the original definition. (I just striped the two blocks with title and name.)

Comment: Thanks, both solutions did the trick. I happened to choose the first one as I read it first. Thanks a lot :)