# Moving the collection of titles from different sections as a side bar

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, presentations

I am not a professional latex user. I have a template for presentation and in the `sty` file, I would like to move the section titles as a side bar similar to this image:
[image]

But I don\t find the place of my logo changes from right top. This is my file:

```
\usetheme{Rochester}


\RequirePackage{pgf}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\beamer@headheight=0.10\paperwidth
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.44}
\definecolor{bluepigment}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{oxygenorange}{rgb}{0.96,0.5,0.04}
\definecolor{oxygengray}{rgb}{0.41,0.41,0.41}
\definecolor{oxygenlightgray}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\definecolor{oxygenblue}{rgb}{0.63,0.79,0.95}
\setbeamercolor*{Title bar}{fg=white, bg=oxygenblue}
\setbeamercolor*{Location bar}{fg=oxygenorange,bg=oxygenlightgray}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=Title bar}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=oxygenblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=oxygenlightgray,fg=oxygengray}
\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{bg=red,fg=white}


\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{bg=white,fg=oxygengray}
\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{bg=oxygenblue,fg=coolblack}

\usecolortheme[named=oxygenorange]{structure}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\tiny,series=\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[opacity=.15]{\includegraphics
[width=\paperwidth]{Social-Network}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{logo}{logocomplete}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{net}{homophily}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{logocomplete}{logocomplete}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vskip -6pt
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.06\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
      \hfill \pgfuseimage{logocomplete}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \vskip-0.25\beamer@headheight
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \vskip-0.2cm
  \hskip-0.5cm\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
  \vskip-0.10em
  \hskip-0.5cm\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
}


\setbeamertemplate{headline\beamer@sidebarside}
{
\beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
%  \vskip -5pt
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@tempdim]{Title bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0pt}{\hskip0.22cm}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@tempdim]{Title bar}
      \hfill \pgfuseimage{net}\pgfuseimage{logo}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \linethickness{0.1pt}
  \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.3\beamer@headheight,sep=0.1cm]{Location bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertshortauthor~|~\insertshorttitle
    \hfill
    \insertframenumber%/\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
}
```

I don't see the **logo** and extra image on the header any longer. Can anyone help to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add a MWE? And maybe a sketch of the intended output would be useful, too.

Comment: @samcarter I added the template that I would like the sidebar looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `\usetheme{Rochester}` in your first line of your code fragment sets the width of the sidebar to zero. You could replace this line for example with

```
\useoutertheme[width=0.10\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
```

to get a sidebar of `.1\paperwidth` (to match the size you specified for your headline). The `\logo{\includegraphics[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{example-image}}` is automatically positioned at the top left.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[width=0.10\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}



\usepackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\logo{\includegraphics[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{example-image}}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\beamer@headheight=0.10\paperwidth
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.44}
\definecolor{bluepigment}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{oxygenorange}{rgb}{0.96,0.5,0.04}
\definecolor{oxygengray}{rgb}{0.41,0.41,0.41}
\definecolor{oxygenlightgray}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\definecolor{oxygenblue}{rgb}{0.63,0.79,0.95}
\setbeamercolor*{Title bar}{fg=white, bg=oxygenblue}
\setbeamercolor*{Location bar}{fg=oxygenorange,bg=oxygenlightgray}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=Title bar}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=oxygenblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=oxygenlightgray,fg=oxygengray}
\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{bg=red,fg=white}


\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{bg=white,fg=oxygengray}
\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{bg=oxygenblue,fg=coolblack}

\usecolortheme[named=oxygenorange]{structure}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\tiny,series=\normalfont}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[opacity=.15]{\includegraphics
[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};\end{tikzpicture}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{logo}{example-image}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{net}{example-image}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\beamer@headheight]{logocomplete}{example-image}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vskip -6pt
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.06\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
      \hfill \pgfuseimage{logocomplete}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
  \vskip-0.25\beamer@headheight
  \vskip-\baselineskip
  \vskip-0.2cm
  \hskip-0.5cm\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
  \vskip-0.10em
  \hskip-0.5cm\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
}


\setbeamertemplate{headline\beamer@sidebarside}
{
\beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
%  \vskip -5pt
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@tempdim]{Title bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0pt}{\hskip0.22cm}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@tempdim]{Title bar}
      \hfill \pgfuseimage{net}\pgfuseimage{logo}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \linethickness{0.1pt}
  \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=.3cm,wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.3\beamer@headheight,sep=0.1cm]{Location bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \insertshortauthor~|~\insertshorttitle
    \hfill
    \insertframenumber%/\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There is a problem. In the side bar I want to cancel out the appearance of title and the presenter because they are already in  footnote. How should I do that?

Comment: @Dalek Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89917/36296

Comment: I actually found this answer and fixed it before you mention it. Thanks